# How to check if an infoWindow is set and on the map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to check first if a infoWindow is set and on the map before use

```
marker.infowindow.close();
```

if this isn't set and not on the map, the script don't work? I was thinking of an if statement to check before close?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to check if an infoWindow exists:

```
var currentInfoWindow = null;

if(currentInfoWindow !== null){
    currentInfoWindow.close();
}
```

Then, after the call to `infoWindow.open()` assign the currentInfoWindow to the new infoWindow:

```
currentInfoWindow = infoWindow;
```

This is especially useful to make sure that only one infoWindow is open on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `typeof` function in Javascript.

```
if (typeof(marker.infowindow) === "undefined"){
//object doesn't exist
}
else{
//the object does exist
marker.infowindow.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give an ID to the div you use as the content of the InfoWindow.
`document.getElementById('content-div-id')` will return the div if the InfoWindow is open on the map, and `null` otherwise.